# How do i get a loop so that for each cell in 4 columns (note each cells per column is a Criteria) it checks for the price in a database

Tags: database, vba, excel, loops

I am writing a Excel file that can get a price form a database depending on 4 Criteria. I got to the point that it can find in one row the price (in the row there are first the 4 criteria and then the price)[See picture[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/60C8l.jpg)]. but what i want is that every row can find the matching price. The code that i have now is this:

```
Option Explicit


Sub cmdSearch_Click()

Dim strCriteriaEquipment As String
Dim strCriteriaType As String
Dim strCriteriaMaterial As String
Dim strCriteriaSize As String
Dim strSQL As String
Dim strSourceTable As String


With Worksheets("Summary")
    strCriteriaEquipment = .Range("B29").Value
    strCriteriaType = .Range("C29").Value
    strCriteriaMaterial = .Range("D29").Value
    strCriteriaSize = .Range("E29").Value

End With



strSourceTable = "[DB$" & Replace(Worksheets("DB").Range("SourceData").Address, "$", "") & "]"
strSQL = "SELECT [Price] FROM " & strSourceTable & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL & "WHERE [Equipment]= """ & strCriteriaEquipment & """" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL & "AND [Type]=""" & strCriteriaType & """" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL & "AND [Material]=""" & strCriteriaMaterial & """" & vbNewLine
strSQL = strSQL & "AND [Size]=""" & strCriteriaSize & """;"
Call TableFetcher(strSQL)


strSQL = vbNullString
strCriteriaEquipment = vbNullString
strCriteriaType = vbNullString
strCriteriaMaterial = vbNullString
strCriteriaSize = vbNullString

strSourceTable = vbNullString

End Sub


 Option Explicit
Public Const adOpenStatic = 3
Public Const adOpenKeySet = 1
Public Const adLockReadOnly = 1

Sub Fetcher(strSQL As String, Optional strDropDownName As String)

Dim rstRecordSet As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
Dim con As Object 'ADODB.Connection
Dim strWorkBookPath As String

strWorkBookPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rstRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strWorkBookPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
rstRecordSet.Open strSQL, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

With Worksheets("Summary")
    With .DropDowns(strDropDownName)
        .RemoveAllItems
        .List = Split(UniqueStringWithDelimiter(rstRecordSet.GetRows, "|"), "|")
        .Value = 1
    End With
End With

rstRecordSet.Close
con.Close
Set rstRecordSet = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
strWorkBookPath = vbNullString

End Sub

Sub TableFetcher(strSQL As String)

Dim rstRecordSet As Object 'ADODB.Recordset
Dim con As Object 'ADODB.Connection
Dim strWorkBookPath As String

strWorkBookPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName

Set con = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
Set rstRecordSet = CreateObject("ADODB.RecordSet")

con.Open "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;" & _
        "Data Source=" & strWorkBookPath & ";" & _
        "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes"";"
rstRecordSet.Open strSQL, con, adOpenStatic, adLockReadOnly

With Worksheets("Summary")

    If Not (rstRecordSet.EOF And rstRecordSet.BOF) Then
        .Range("ResultTable").Cells(5).CopyFromRecordset rstRecordSet
    Else
        .Range("ResultTable").Cells(5).Value = "Data Not Found!"
    End If
End With

rstRecordSet.Close
con.Close
Set rstRecordSet = Nothing
Set con = Nothing
strWorkBookPath = vbNullString

End Sub

Public Function UniqueStringWithDelimiter(varArray As Variant, strDelimiter As String) As Variant

Dim varTemp() As Variant
Dim lngLoop As Long
Dim strConcat As String
ReDim Preserve varTemp(0 To 0)
varTemp(0) = varArray(0, 0)
strConcat = strConcat & varArray(0, 0)
For lngLoop = 1 To UBound(varArray, 2)
    If InStr(1, strConcat, varArray(0, lngLoop), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
        strConcat = strConcat & strDelimiter & varArray(0, lngLoop)
    End If
Next lngLoop

UniqueStringWithDelimiter = strConcat.
strConcat = vbNullString
Erase varTemp

End Function
```

How i do change the code so it does what i need it to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I think i'm reading is that, if four (4) criteria are met, you would then find a price.  Have you used an If statement with AND modifier utilizing your four (4) criteria?

This could happen in a loop, such as:

```
Dim r as Long, c as Long, LR as Long
LR = Cells(Rows.Count,1).End(xlUp).Row 'Assumes column 1 is contiguous
For r = 1 to LR
    c=4 'assumes you're starting with column 4
    If Cells(r,c).Value="Blah" AND Cells(r,c+1).Value ="Moo" AND Cells(r,c+2).Value="Ruff" AND Cells(r,c+3).Value="Shamoo" Then
        Cells(r,c+4).Copy 
    End If
Next r
```

Comment: thats what i want but then i want "Blah" "Moo" "Ruff" "Shamoo" to be range.
so that when i type like:
Column A , B, C, D, E
         pump, A, Iron, DN10, [price]
         Pump, B, PVC, DN10, [price]
so the  .value= need to be cells in a column but so that every cell is seen induvidualy and not as a range
i don't know if this is a good discription or not :$

Comment: @jps Then you would write something like *sheets("NAME1").cells(r,c).Value = Sheets("NAME2").Cells(x,y).Value.  Either way, you would use that AND modifier, and list all of your criteria.  You could also do a Match() function, provided you have at least one unique value (e.g., a tracking number) then you can match to that value, and use the row value to compare against the other criteria.

Comment: @jps Just saw you edited your comment beyond "A, B, C, D, E"; each cell individually is particularly why the loop is used.  For r = 1 to LR (LR = last row), you are using Cells(r,1) Cells(r,2) Cells(r,3) Cells (r,4) each to compare individually, but requiring ALL criteria met to be True.  That r means that in one iteration of the loop, row r (changing number) is reviewed.

Comment: Okey thank you for explaining :) i think i get it :D

Comment: @jps Good luck!  Just remember that if you are using multiple sheets, you will need to declare your objects fully.  Specifically, if Sheet2 has the reference/prices you want, and you have your list on Sheet1, then the LR should be With Sheets("Sheet2")  LR = .Cells( .Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row  End With, to ensure you're using the correct sheet for the correct items.